# Session data is not available after refresh

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-variables

I was trying learning session with PHP and while creating an auth app I found that when I do a hard refresh (click on the URL & hit Refresh) the session data gets lost even if it's not 3000sec as I set. I really need your help here. I have been stuck here for two days and can't find any solution. First I tried on PHP live server localhost:3030 and then also tried on live hosting site but still no luck. Please help me here.

```
<?php
        session_name('auth_app');
        session_start([
                'cookie_lifetime' => 3000,
        ]);
        $loggedin = logged_value() ?? false ;
        function logged_value() {
            if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
                if('admin' == $_POST['username'] && 'a51e47f646375ab6bf5dd2c42d3e6181' == md5($_POST['password'])) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $loggedin;
        if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false;
            session_destroy();
        }
    ?>
    
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column column-60 column-offset-20">
                    <h2>AUTH Example</h2>
                    <?php
                    if( true == $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) {
                        printf("<p>Hello %s, Welcome!</p>", $_POST['username']);
                    }else {
                        printf("<p>Hello %s, Welcome!</p>", 'Stranger' );
                    }
                        ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column column-60 column-offset-20">
                    <?php if(false == $_SESSION['loggedin']) : ?>
                    <form method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                        <button type="submit" class="button-primary" name="submit">Login</button>
                    </form>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <form method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="logout" value="1">
                            <button type="submit" class="button-primary" name="submit">Logout</button>
                        </form>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your `if(isset($_POST['logout']))` check is always going to be true because `isset()` is only going to return `false` if `$_POST['logout']` is null. So everytime you submit the form the input is there.

Comment: the line `$_SESSION['loggedin'] == false; ` should be `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;` in the logout block

Comment: @Sherif - That's usually how people check if a form is submitted so I don't really see the issue with that? If the logout form is submitted, the `logout` post value will exist and that's probably when they want to runt their logout code.

Comment: One issue you have is that you _always_ set: `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = $loggedin;`. If you're logged in and visit this page, it will set the session `$_SESSION['loggedin'] ` to `false` since the function `logged_value()` then won't return anything (and hence set `$loggedin` to `false`).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson if I set `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;` without using a function only into the if condition of isset it solves my issue but there is a warning `Undefined array key "loggedin"`

Answer (score 0):

use direct session timeout because session start cant count seconds `cookie_lifetime`

```
session_start();
header('Refresh: 3000; url=logout.php');
```